# store dictionary to hashtable

Tags: c#, hashtable

I'm working on a scrabble cheater sort of program, where the user enters a group of letters and, after the letters are jumbled around a bit, they are compared to a word list I have stored in a database.  Because searching through the database for each letter combination is so slow, I tried storing the words in a List first, so they would be available in memory, which really improved performance.  But I would like to make it faster yet by storing the word lists in List in a Hashtable where the key is the first letter of the word, but I'm  a little stuck on how to go about it.

What I have (and obviously won't work) is:

```
public Hashtable populateWordTable()
    {
        Hashtable wordTable = new Hashtable();
        List<string> wordTableWordList = new List<string>();
        connect = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand find = new SqlCommand("Select * FROM English order by Word", connect);
        // starting with first record, store each word into the List<string> wordlist
        SqlDataReader dr = null;
        int found = 0;
        try
        {
            connect.Open();
            dr = find.ExecuteReader();
            string key = string.Empty;
            string keyStartingPosition = "a";
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                // if word is present
                if (!dr.IsDBNull(0))
                {
                    found = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]);
                    key = dr[1].ToString().Substring(0, 1);                        
                }
                if (found > 0)
                {
                    // if we have transitioned to the next letter in the alphabet
                    if (key != keyStartingPosition)
                    {
                        wordTable.Add(keyStartingPosition, wordTableWordList);
                        List<string> newList = new List<string>();
                        newList.Add(dr[1].ToString());
                        keyStartingPosition = key;
                    }
                    // still in the same letter in the alphabet
                    else
                    {
                        wordTableWordList.Add(dr[1].ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            connect.Close();
        }

        return wordTable;
    }
```

Comment: HashTables aren't sorted collections by nature, and you can't define keys. You should use a Dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having done something like this before, I found the best structure was a DAWG ([directed acyclic word graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_acyclic_finite_state_automaton)). I translated [Steve Hanov's Python DAWG builder](http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=115) to C# last year, but lost it when a RAID drive went bad. Shouldn't be too hard for you to translate to C#.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `Dictionary<char, IEnumerable<string>>` ([Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)). Its usage is rather straightforward, when you add words you first check if it `ContainsKey(word[0])`, and if it doesn't you `Add` it. You could first assign an empty list, and fill it through each iteration, or build the list first and then assign it to the key. It's up to you.

Comment: If you do use this method, instead of having an IEnumerable<String>, use an IEnumerable containing structs which have the next character found and a flag indicating if it ends a word. See my answer about DAWGs for more info.

Comment: Yours is probably a better suited implementation for this specific case. Mine is more the generic way. I think that the OP should use your answer instead, but I'll leave mine as generic reference.

Comment: KappaG3, I'm trying to implement your recommended approach, but won't I still have the same problem with iteration that I discuss with the Hashtable?  Dictionary may be the better way to go for a couple reasons, I'm just stuck on my approach to iteration.

Comment: Excuse me, but I fail to see where you mentioned the problem? If it's slowness, the way I'd deal with the whole thing is the following. [build the dictionary]: create a Dictionary<char, IEnumerable<string> -> iterate through each word of the raw table and if key is missing, add it with a new List<string> as value -> add each iterated word to the corresponding list. Then, when you need to compare the input with a word, you just iterate through the already built dictionary at the given key. (ex. myDict[input[0]]).

Comment: I'm sorry you're right - I didn't explain myself very well.  The problem I'm having is how to save the words from the database table to the Dictionary<char, IEnumerable<string>>.  Looking at the code snippet above where I tried to do this with a hashtable, you should be able to see that the code obviously won't work, so I was hoping for a suggestion to get over this hurdle.  I have everything else working nicely, or I did when I was using the List<sting> approach, and I expect it won't be all that much different with the Dictionary approach.  Thanks for your help to this point.